# How to find Young's elastic modulus of a sphere using a camera?

Tags: collision, elasticity

So I have a deformable ball and a high-speed camera. How do I measure Young's elastic modulus?

I was thinking of looking at the coefficient of restitution of the ball, but it doesn't seem to be directly related to the elastic modulus, to my surprise (I might be wrong, though). Alternatively, I could use Hertzian contact laws, but this gives me the corrected elastic modulus, which also contains Poisson's ratio, which I do not have. I have only one ball size.

Do you have any suggestions?

Comment: What do you know about the material?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that you could use the Hertzian contact problem for this.

Let's say that you have a plane surface with a Young modulus and a mass that are much higher than the ones from your sphere. You can use the equation

$$h_0 = \left(\frac{m}{k}\right)^{2/5} v^{4/5}\, ,$$

with $m$ the mass of your sphere, and $v$ its speed. Here, $h_0$ represents the deformation when the sphere starts to bounce back. If your sphere is much more compliant than your surface you can assume that all the deformation is happening in that object. The speed is the value you achieve just before impact, so you can vary it with different initial heights. Actually, the equation above is obtained from a balance of energy, so you could rederive it for different heights instead of speeds (see reference).

The other parameters are:

$$k = \frac{4}{5D}\sqrt{R}\, ,$$

with $R$ the radius of the sphere and

$$D = \frac{3}{4}\frac{(1 - \nu^2)}{E}\, .$$

You could vary $v$ and then perform a nonlinear regression to find $\nu$ and $E$.

#### Reference

- Landau, L. D., & Lifshitz, E. M. (1986). Theory of elasticity (Vol. 7, No. 3). New York: Pergamon Press, Oxford.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Just to be clear, in the first equation $h_0$ is the height of the penetration (i.e the part of the sphere diameter that is truncated by the collision at max deformation ?) and v is the speed just before the impact ? So varying $v$ can be achevied by varying the fall height for example ( in case of a free fall on the ground) ?

Comment: Also, do you have any reference for the penetration equation ? I can't find it online. Thanks again !

Comment: after thinking about the problem, I am really not sure about what $h_0$ is. It cannot be just the one I guessed previously as the sphere is deformed and therefore is more like a truncated ellispoid at this point. I would really appreciate if you could elaborate on $h_0$.

Comment: @BrivaëlCollin, you could get $h$ as the change in diameter for your sphere.